# Announcement: Genealogy Stack Exchange gets award

Tags: discussion, publicity

The Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange site has been awarded Honourable Mention in the Best Genealogy Product of 2012 category in [Tamura Jones' GeneAwards 2012](http://www.tamurajones.net/GeneAwards2012.xhtml).

> honourable mention: Genealogy Stack Exchange (GENSE)
>
> There already
>   are many places to ask genealogy questions. Vendors have their blogs,
>   wikis, forums and bulletin boards. The new Genealogy Stack Exchange
>   site is a vendor-neutral Question & Answer site for genealogy & family
>   history. You can follow the twitter feed to be alerted to new
>   questions.

Comment: That's great! Congratulations, folks. Looks like your hard word is paying off.

Comment: I upvoted this but it is an announcement not a question so I have also voted to close it.  Maybe there is another way to may an announcement on SE Genealogy.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Then what is the correct media to make an announcement of interest to people of this SE, if not through the meta? I looked, but can't track down any official rules on this on SE. Will it make a difference if I change it to a question, as I now have?

Comment: @PolyGeo Meta can be used for anything.

Comment: Perhaps SE Genealogy needs a [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) like a number of other SE communities.  That would be an ideal place for announcements but in the meantime @lkessler's choice of Meta is probably best - perhaps started with "Announcement:" like SE Mathematics does [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/announcement-private-contacts-by-moderators).

Comment: @PolyGeo - Okay, I've done that. And I've added an "announcement" tag as well.

Comment: The existence of an "Announcement" tag can only increase the chances of similar notices being posted. Would anyone care to write a "rule" that distinguishes this from an advertisement for an Genealogy Conference? New tag {SLIPPERY SLOPE}

Comment: @Fortiter - Well, the announcement must always have to do specifically with Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange

Comment: @lkessler An [announcement] tag would be subject to easy abuse. The other tags work fine for this Q.

Comment: As a blogger, Tamura Jones is entitled to use a personal platform for pushing barrows (as we all do). The GeneAwards 2012 are no exception, as we might expect. I did struggle to find any acknowledgement on the site of potential "conflict of interest" that just might have coloured some of the statements.